# How can i measure disk size using elixir?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

i am new into `elixir` and  `phoenix`. I have found in `erlang`, to check disk space using [--diskup](http://erlang.org/doc/man/disksup.html). And i have found another function/statement inside elixir to check total memory usage:

```
> :erlang.memory(:total)
```

My question is how can check disk size/space of my current system ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The disksup module belongs to the os_mon application which in turn is dependent on the sasl application. Therefore you need to start these applications before you call.

```
> :application.start(:sasl)
> :application.start(:os_mon)
> :disksup.get_disk_data()
```

Now you can use all functions similar with Erlang.

Comment: This is noted in the doc linked in the original question, but to anyone (like me) who didn't read the docs first: get_disk_data does not update its value on every call, but rather gets the most recent value from a scheduled check which by default happens once every 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just do os:cmd("df") in erlang.